# VBA Excel - Move entire row based on 2 criteria to another sheet upon a change

Tags: excel, vba

Is there code to be able to completely move an entire row based on if column F states "complete" OR "discontinued" to another worksheet within the same workbook on the next available row?

This is what I have tried. But, I want it to occur upon a CHANGE in column F. Also, I want it for both "Complete" AND "Discontinued" criteria. The way it is written does not accommodate that.

```
Sub MoveRowsToCompletedTasks()

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

' Set the source and target sheets
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tasks")
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed Tasks")

' Find the last row in the source sheet
lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through each row in the source sheet
For i = 2 To lastRow
    ' Check if cell in column F contains "Complete" or "Discontinued"
    If sourceSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "Complete" Then
        ' Copy the entire row to the target sheet
        sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        ' Delete row from the source sheet
        sourceSheet.Rows(i).Delete
        ' Decrement the loop counter as the rows are shifting up
        i = i - 1
        ' Update the last row value
        lastRow = lastRow - 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: So for each change in the F-column, you'd want to trigger the macro to copy all of the corresponding rows or do you not want this to happen on *every* change in the F-column?

Comment: Hi @Notus_Panda, I would want it to happen on every change in the F-column.

Comment: Seems a bit extreme, no? Imagine typing "goods", then correcting yourself to "good" and you've added all the rows with "Complete"/"Discontinued" twice then.  Would there be any logic behind not adding rows that are already there, i.e. with a unique key of some sorts?

Comment: No, it would just be at the change of that column only. I am new to VBA so I do not know how to write it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to get move multiple rows at once is using a `Union` Range object.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveRowsToCompletedTasks()

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet 
Dim CopyRng As Range  
Dim i as Long, lastRow As Long

' Set the source and target sheets
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tasks")
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed Tasks")

With sourceSheet
    ' Find the last row in the source sheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each row in the source sheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Check if cell in column F contains "Complete" or "Discontinued"
        If .Cells(i, "F").Value = "Complete" Or .Cells(i, "F").Value = "Discontinued" Then
            If CopyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRng = .Cells(i, "F")
            Else
                Set CopyRng = Application.Union(CopyRng, .Cells(i, "F"))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With    

' make sure there's at least 1 row that needs to be moved
If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
    CopyRng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    CopyRng.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

If you want to call this Routine every time a cell is modified in column F in "Tasks" worksheet, place the following code in "Tasks" **Worksheet Module**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' check if value modified in column F
If Target.Column = 6 Then
    ' ~~~ Call Sub that moves rows from "Tasks" worksheet to "Completes Tasks" worksheet ~~~
    MoveRowsToCompletedTasks
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

screenshot of adding to 'Tasks' worksheet module:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Shai Rado, that works only if I click the Run Dialog button; however, I need it to automatically do this when I change the cell from a working on status to either "Complete" or "Discontinued".  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @MeliKay did you add also the 2nd piece of code to your worksheet module?

Comment: I did. Above the Sub code. But, it is not working automatically.

Comment: @MeliKay check my updated answer above, I've added a screenshot to where you need to place this code.

Comment: That worked! THANK YOU!! EXCEPT, it deletes the previous task that was moved to the completed tasks tab. It needs to add to a row below.

Comment: That worked! THANK YOU!! EXCEPT, it deletes the previous task that was moved to the completed tasks tab. It needs to add to a row below.

Comment: @MeliKay can you post a new question with a screenshot to show what is deleted and what is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in my PC.

I put your code in Task sheet's module.  Filled some rows in Tasks tab as below.   Tried to change "Complete" F column of the row 10-12 from Tasks tab, the row was moved to Completed Task sheet.

[image: Tasks tab]

[image: Completed Task tab]

Comment: Hi! thank you. The code that I am trying to change is this part:  sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) specifially changing "A" to "F". That is where I am getting the

Comment: I added my test file link as below. It is your original code. Down load file and try it at your end. 
https://github.com/dython/stackoverflow/blob/9761f7474864f7a8365beb0d6d342f54706e965d/Test1.xlsm