I want to copy data depending on a value from one sheet to another, and instantly delete the copied data and remove the now empty rows
The company I work for keeps track of malfunctions in a source sheet called "Storingen" (malfunctions). Whenever the malfunction has been dealt with, they change the status (in column D) to "Opgelost" (solved). Once a week we discuss every malfunction and when this meeting is over, I want to press a button to copy all the rows with data about the malfuctions who have been solved to a worksheet called "Archief" (archive). I want the data to be copied to the first empty row in the sheet, so no empty rows are created and everything is copied to the archive in a chronological order. Always the latest data at the bottom row.
The copied data needs to be removed from the source sheet, leaving only the rows that where not dealt with. So we always have a clear view of what still needs to be done. I want to remove all empty rows where once the -copied/now deleted- rows where.
I have tried to make a sub that copies all the data, and this works fine for me (I put it in the block below). But I just cannot seem to grasp how I do all the other things that I just described. I have tried advanced filtering and random bits of coding from the internet. But I can't seem to get i to work
Sub Archiveer()
    If MsgBox("Wil je deze data archiveren?", vbOKCancel, "Let op!") = vbOK Then
        Sheets("Archief").Unprotect Password:="Smits"
        Worksheets("Storingen").Select
        Range("3:100").Copy
        Worksheets("Archief").Activate
        Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("Storingen").Select
        Range("3:100").ClearContents
        Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select
        Sheets("Archief").Protect Password:="Smits"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

If anyone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated!

This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77201995/vba-excel-move-entire-row-based-on-2-criteria-to-another-sheet-upon-a-change

Did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79210033/ answer your question?

SIde note: consider avoiding Select in your code

Iterate through the source table to check the values in column D, copy the matching rows to the target sheet, and delete all matched rows in a single operation at the end.
Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)


Application.Union method (Excel)


Range.End property (Excel)

Sub MoveRowsToCompletedJobs()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, targetCell As Range
    Dim i As Long, ColCnt As Long, delRng As Range
    Const KEY_COL = "D" ' modify as needed
    Const FIRST_DATA_ROW = 3 ' modify as needed
    ' Set the source and target sheets
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Storingen")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archief")
    
    ' Find the last row in the source sheet
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, KEY_COL).End(xlUp).Row
    ColCnt = sourceSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
    ' Loop through each row in the source sheet
    For i = lastRow To FIRST_DATA_ROW Step -1
        ' Check if cell in column D contains "Opgelost"
        If sourceSheet.Cells(i, KEY_COL).Value = "Opgelost" Then
            ' Copy the data row to the target sheet
            Set targetCell = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
            ' If Excel table (ListObject) on the target sheeet, get the target cell in table
            If Len(targetCell.Value) = 0 Then
                Set targetCell = targetCell.End(xlUp)
            End If
            sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, ColCnt).Copy Destination:=targetCell.Offset(1)
            ' collect cells to delete at the end
            If delRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRng = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1)
            Else
                Set delRng = Union(delRng, sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then
        delRng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub

